# I want data in following format

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am working with some API & I managed to format the data in this order:
***Data is in this format***

```
const data = [
    [
        {
            "point":
            [
                "3",
                "4"
            ],
        },
        {
            "point":
            [
                "5",
                "6"
            ],
        },
        {
            "point":
            [
                "7",
                "8"
            ],
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "point":
            [
                "9",
                "10"
            ],
        },
        {
            "point":
            [
                "11",
                "12"
            ],
        },
        {
            "point":
            [
                "13",
                "14"
            ],
        },
        {
            "point":
            [
                "15",
                "16"
            ],
        },
    ]
];
```

From the above data, I want to extract point properties in this order.
***Output is required as:***

```
[
    {
        series: {
            data: [[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
        }
    },
    {
        series: {
            data: [[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14],[15,16]]
        }
    },
]
```

As I proceeded to work, I got to know I am in need of help. As I am starter in this field, I would like to ask for some help.

I have tried doing:

```
const required = data.map((_, index) => {
  return {
    series: {
      data: data.slice(0, index + 1).map(i => [i[0].point[0], i[0].point[1]])
    }
  }
})
```

I am able to get first element of each array. I could not figure out to include all elements. It is because I have used ***i[0]*** . I am not able loop due to lack of my experience.
***Output I got:***

```
[
    {
        series: {
            data: [[3,4]]
        }
    },
    {
        series: {
            data: [[3,4],[9,10]]
        }
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers presented here appear to present the series array as one of strings.
Your required output clearly shows them as numbers, not the strings that would represent them. The following code performs the conversion.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false)

function onLoaded(evt) {
  var result = data.map(func);
  console.log(result);

  function func(el, index, collection) {
    let tmpResult = {
      series: {
        data: []
      }
    };
    el.forEach(pointFunc);

    function pointFunc(pointObj) {
      tmpResult.series.data.push(pointObj.point.map(el => parseFloat(el)));
    }
    return tmpResult;
  }
}

const data = [
  [{
      "point": [
        "3",
        "4"
      ],
    },
    {
      "point": [
        "5",
        "6"
      ],
    },
    {
      "point": [
        "7",
        "8"
      ],
    },
  ],
  [{
      "point": [
        "9",
        "10"
      ],
    },
    {
      "point": [
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
    },
    {
      "point": [
        "13",
        "14"
      ],
    },
    {
      "point": [
        "15",
        "16"
      ],
    },
  ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use index, like pass index instead of 0.. `i[index]`

Answer (score 0):

```
let required = data.map(series => ({
    'series': {
        'data': series.map(i => [parseInt(i.point[0]), parseInt(i.point[1])]) // parseInt to convert the strings into numbers
    }
}))

// we use this to add [[3, 4], ...] to the second series [[9, 10], ...].
// To be exactly: it makes that every series includes the previous ones.
required.forEach((_, index) => {
    if (index == 0) return 
    
    required[index].series.data = [...required[index - 1].series.data, ...required[index].series.data]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need `map` here:

```js
var data = [ [ { "point": [ "3", "4" ], }, { "point": [ "5", "6" ], }, { "point": [ "7", "8" ], }, ], [ { "point": [ "9", "10" ], }, { "point": [ "11", "12" ], }, { "point": [ "13", "14" ], }, { "point": [ "15", "16" ], }]];

var result = data.map(k=>k.map(l=>l.point.map(Number))).map((k, i, self)=>[...(self[i-1]??[]), ...k]).map(k=>({series:{data:k}}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`, `flatMap` and `Object.values` will simplify.

```js
const convert = (data) =>
  data.map((arr) => ({ series: { data: arr.flatMap(Object.values) } }));

const data = [
    [
        {
            "point":
            [
                "3",
                "4"
            ],
        },
        {
            "point":
            [
                "5",
                "6"
            ],
        },
        {
            "point":
            [
                "7",
                "8"
            ],
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "point":
            [
                "9",
                "10"
            ],
        },
        {
            "point":
            [
                "11",
                "12"
            ],
        },
        {
            "point":
            [
                "13",
                "14"
            ],
        },
        {
            "point":
            [
                "15",
                "16"
            ],
        },
    ]
];

console.log(convert(data));
```